# Asp.net: Why is my session reads only one row of a column in ASP.NET grid view?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

I'm trying to read values from a certain column in an ASP.NET Grid View. But when I try to create a session to read them it only reads one row. Any idea what is the possible cause?

This is my code:

```
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("select distinct Name,assignment_id, Description ,cod from assignments 
            INNER Join crmsLecturerXCrsSection ON crmsLecturerXCrsSection.emp_key = assignments.emp_key
            INNER Join CRMSStudentsXCrsSection ON CRMSStudentsXCrsSection.CrsSec_id = crmsLecturerXCrsSection.CrsSec_id
            INNER JOIN CRMS_CourseXSection ON CRMS_CourseXSection.CrsSec_id = CRMSStudentsXCrsSection.CrsSec_id
            INNER JOIN CRMSECTIONS ON CRMSECTIONS.SEC_ID = CRMS_CourseXSection.SEC_ID
            left JOIN crmscourses ON crmscourses.crs_id = CRMS_CourseXSection.crs_id
            INNER JOIN CRMS_CourseXSection cs ON CRMS_CourseXSection.SEC_ID = CRMSECTIONS.SEC_ID
            INNER JOIN CRMSSEMESTER ON CRMSSEMESTER.SEM_ID = CRMS_CourseXSection.SEM_ID
            where  CRMSSEMESTER.SEM_ID='1'   
            and crmsLecturerXCrsSection.emp_key='436' and crmscourses.crs_desc='" + Session("crs") + "'", con)



        Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
        Dim dt As New DataTable()

        da.Fill(dt)

        Dim row As DataRow
        For Each row In dt.Rows
            Session("assid") = row("assignment_id").ToString()
        Next
```

And this is the other page code:

```
 Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim con As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("dbconnection").ConnectionString)
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("select * from assignments where assignment_id='" + Session("assid") + "'", con)
        Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
```

Here I want to read the assignment's id so I can pass it to another page and it gets passed but only the first row.

Comment: This piece of code does exactly that, pass only the first row id `Session("assid") = dt.Rows(0)("assignment_id").ToString()` if you want all the IDs you need to pass a list of them

Comment: @J.Salas thank you for pointing this out.  I tried to add a for each so it could read all rows but it still read one random row.

Comment: You are reading all rows, but overwrite that session value. So at the end only the last one is still stored. So collect a list and store *that* in session

Answer (score 1):

Try  something like this:

```
    Dim listIDs As New List(Of String)
    Dim row As DataRow
    For Each row In dt.Rows
        listIDs.Add(row("assignment_id").ToString())
    Next
    Session("assid") = listIDs;
```

And then in the other function you could get all assignments like:

```
   Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("select * from assignments where assignment_id in ('" + String.Join("','", Session("assid")) + "')", con)
```

You would want to check if list is null or empty at the begin of the ButtonClick function as best practice, using a select * also is a bad idea, but as learning practice this would work.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. I tried it but it didn't pass the values, instead it showed me this :System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]